# Setting featured image with function, 1 part not working

Tags: functions, post-thumbnails

I'm trying to set a post's featured image based on custom fields. There are different types of posts and therefore the featured image should be set depending on which custom fields have been filled out.

Here is what I currently have (edited):

```
//Set post thumbnail based on various conditions
        if (get_post_meta($post_id, 'featured_image', true)) {
            $attachment_id = get_post_meta($post_id, 'featured_image', true);
        } elseif (get_post_meta($post_id, 'upload_single_image', true)) {
            $attachment_id = get_post_meta($post_id, 'upload_single_image', true);
        } elseif (get_post_meta($post_id, 'create_gallery', false)) {
            $gallery = get_post_meta($post_id, 'create_gallery', false);//get the full gallery
            $attachment_id = $gallery[0]['upload_image']; //Get image from first row    
        }
```

The first two conditions are working, but the third condition (create gallery) isn't. I thought that getting the first row of the db table and then calling the name of the custom meta data would do it, but it's not working.

Anyone see what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Some more context: Each custom field outputs the ID of an image. I've double checked that this it the case. Also, 'create_gallery' retrieves two values, 'upload_image' and 'image_caption'. I am using the plugin Advanced Custom Fields to loop through this data to allow my users to create galleries of images/captions. I just want to the first image in the table to be the featured image.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the [`$single` paramter of `get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta#Return_Value) to false (or don't set it) to get an array.

Here is a sped-up version:

```
    if ($attachment_id = get_post_meta($post_id, 'featured_image',      true)) :
elseif ($attachment_id = get_post_meta($post_id, 'upload_single_image', true)) :
elseif ($attachment_id = get_post_meta($post_id, 'create_gallery',     false)) :
    $attachment_id = $attachment_id[0]['upload_image'];
endif;
```

**Note**: I did not test this.

---

**// EDIT**
Here is the code with the ACF function:

```
    if ($attachment_id = get_post_meta($post_id, 'featured_image',      true)) :
elseif ($attachment_id = get_post_meta($post_id, 'upload_single_image', true)) :
elseif ($gallery = get_field('create_gallery', $post_id)) :
    $attachment_id = $gallery[0]['upload_image'];
endif;
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I have updated the question with my current code based on your answer. But it's still not setting the first image as the featured image for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work by using ACF's custom functions instead of wp's meta functions.

Final working result:

```
//Set post thumbnail based on various conditions
        if (get_post_meta($post_id, 'featured_image', true)) {
            $attachment_id = get_post_meta($post_id, 'featured_image', true);
        } elseif (get_post_meta($post_id, 'upload_single_image', true)) {
            $attachment_id = get_post_meta($post_id, 'upload_single_image', true);
        } elseif (get_field('create_gallery', $post_id)) {
            $gallery = get_field('create_gallery', $post_id);//get the full gallery
            $attachment_id = $gallery[0]['upload_image']; //Get image from first row    
        }
```

Comment: Hey, nice you figured the last case out by yourself, however, you really should use the `if`-`elseif` construct like I did, otherwise you'd call each of the `get_*` functions twice, which is unnecessary. See my updated answer on this.

Comment: I see. I've never structured my conditionals like that, but I guess it makes sense to not have to call it twice. I'll go ahead and change it. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Well, it's not the _ordinary_ conditional structure, that's right. But in this very case - where you want to set the value of a variable by a function, under the circumstance that the function **does** return something (meaning: not null, false etc.) - **then** you can do it like illustrated in my answer. Your approach is definitley the intuitive one, and for most of the time anyone would do it like that. Here, it would mean each function is called twice, though.